# How do I output the JMeter summary report table data to a .csv file?

Tags: csv, logging, jmeter

I have my JMeter test running through linux command line to write the Summary Report to a .csv file. I want the .csv file to contain the data the Summary Report table shows like below:

*summary +      1 in     1s =    1.3/s Avg:   490 Min:   490 Max:   490 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 4 Started: 4 Finished: 0*

However, the file contains:

*1470313710996,490,HTTP Request,200,OK,Sans - Generate OAuth Token 3-1,text,true,655,1,4,482*

I'n not even entirely sure what data this is representing other than the name of the thread and the HTTP code.

Can someone please help me output the desired data into the.csv file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation before and I was also not sure about data generated by Jmeter. Then I passed these parameters along with csv filename to Jmeter for generating all the useful data.

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -l ".\testresult.csv"
```